# How to read a first string with leading white space in c?

Tags: c, whitespace

I try to get strings as many as the input value in c. 
 
But a leading white space located first line is removed.

I had already use the fgets and scanset. I want the input and output to be the same.

```c
fgets(str[i], 100, stdin);
```

```c
scanf("%[^\n]%*c]", str);
```

**Code**

```c
int n = 0;
scanf("%d\n", &n);

char str[10][100] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fgets(str[i], 100, stdin);
}
```

**Input**

```
3
 **
*
 **
```

**Output**

```
**
*
 **
```

What should I do?

Comment: Why do you use a `\n` after `%d` ??? I think that is taking all the whitespace before the asterisks.

Comment: Perhaps I was tried to get '\n' in the buffer at once.

Comment: if you use `fgets()` you should check if the last character of the input is actually a `\n'`, as not being so could mean any of two things: 1) the buffer was filled completely without giving space to put the last `'\n'` or 2) The user signalled the end of the file, pressing Ctrl-D to the terminal.  This second behaviour can be annoying sometimes, as the `read()` that `fgets()` does internally is just called once (`fgets()` doesn't retry reading to fill the buffer untill full or a `\'n'` is seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use getchar() after reading n because the newline character '\n' will remain in the input buffer and your fgets in for loop will read that and also remove `\n` from scanf.

Use following line of code:

```
    int n = 0;
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    getchar();
    char str[10][100] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      fgets(str[i], 100, stdin);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed description! 
It works after removing "\n".

Answer (score 0):

remove the "\n" from `scanf` and add a `getchar()` to capture the newline.

```
scanf("%d", &n);
getchar();
```